# Show that the limit is equal to the supremum

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu )$ a space of finite measure and $f$ a bounded integrable function.

Show that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{||f||_{n+1}^{n+1}}{||f||_n^n}=||f||_{\infty}$$

$$$$

We have that $$||f||_{n+1}^{n+1}=\int |f|^{n+1} d \mu$$ $$||f_n^n=\int |f|^n d \mu$$ So we get $$ \frac{||f||_{n+1}^{n+1}}{||f||_n^n}=\frac{\int |f|^{n+1} d \mu}{\int |f|^n d \mu}$$

Is it correct so far?? How could we continue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're correct so far. Since $\mu(X) < \infty$, by Holder's inequality, $$\|f\|_n^n = \|f^n\|_1 \le \|1\|_{n+1}\|f^n\|_{(n+1)/n} = \mu(X)^{1/(n+1)}\|f\|_{n+1}^n.$$ Thus $$\frac{\|f\|_{n+1}^{n+1}}{\|f\|_n^n} \ge \mu(X)^{-1/(n+1)}\|f\|_{n+1}.$$ Since $\|f\|_{n+1} \to \|f\|_\infty$, $$\liminf_{n\to \infty} \frac{\|f\|_{n+1}^{n+1}}{\|f\|_n^n} \ge \|f\|_\infty.$$ On the other hand,

$$\|f\|_{n+1}^{n+1} = \int_X |f|^{n+1}\, d\mu = \int_X |f|^n |f|\, d\mu \le \int_X |f|^n \|f\|_\infty \, d\mu = \|f\|_n^n\|f\|_\infty.$$ Therefore $\|f\|_{n+1}^{n+1}/\|f\|_n^n \le \|f\|_\infty$ for all $n$, yielding $$\limsup_{n\to \infty} \frac{\|f\|_{n+1}^{n+1}}{\|f\|_n^n} \le \|f\|_\infty.$$ Therefore

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\|f\|_{n+1}^{n+1}}{\|f\|_n^n} = \|f\|_\infty.$$

Comment: From th second line we have that $$||f||_n^n \leq \mu (X)^{1/(n+1)} ||f||_{n+1}^n \Rightarrow \frac{||f||_{n+1}^n}{||f||_n^n} \geq \mu (X)^{-1/(n+1)}$$ So do we not get  the following?? $$\frac{||f||_{n+1}^{n+1}}{||f||_n^n}=\frac{||f||_{n+1}^n ||f||_{n+1}}{||f||_n^n} \geq \mu (X)^{-1/(n+1)} ||f||_{n+1}$$ 

Or have I done something wrong? 

Then does it always stand that $$||f||_n \rightarrow ||f||_{\infty}$$ ?? At which point do we use the fact that $f$ is a bounded and integrable function?? @kobe

Comment: @Mary I had a typo there, sorry about that. Since $f$ is bounded and integrable, and since $\mu$ is finite, each of the norms $\|f\|_n$ are finite and $\|f\|_\infty$ is finite. Yes, $\|f\|_n\to \|f\|_\infty$ stands -- you can find a similar result in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis text.

Comment: Ok... so do we have to say that since $$||f||_n \rightarrow ||f||_{\infty}$$ we have also that $$||f||_{n+1} \rightarrow ||f||_{\infty}$$ ?? And how do we continue?? How do we get $$\lim inf \frac{||f||_{n+1}^{n+1}}{||f||_n^n} \geq ||f||_{\infty}$$ ?? @kobe

Comment: So we have that $$\frac{||f||_{n+1}^{n+1}}{||f||_n^n} \geq \mu (X)^{-1/(n+1)} ||f||_{n+1}$$ 

$$\Rightarrow\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{||f||_{n+1}^{n+1}}{||f||_n^n} \geq \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}\mu (X)^{-1/(n+1)} ||f||_{n+ 1}=\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}||f||_{n+ 1}$$ 

Is it correct so far?? 

How do we conclude that $$\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}||f||_{n+ 1}=||f||_{\infty}$$ ?? @kobe

Comment: I got stuck right now... How do we know that $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} ||f||_{n+1}$ exists and that it is equal to $||f||_{\infty}$ ?? Do we have to justify it ? Or can we consider it as a matter of fact?? @kobe

Comment: @MaryStar I added the details for the limsup inequality. Please review my edit.

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!!! :-) @kobe

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\frac{\|f\|_{n+1}^{n+1}}{\|f\|_n^n}=\left(\frac{\|f\|_{n+1}}{\|f\|_n}\right)^n\|f\|_{n+1}. $$
The result follows from$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f\|_n\to\|f\|_{\infty}.$$

Comment: That might be correct, but is not obvious as stated. For example, $1 + 1/n \to 1$, but $(1+1/n)^n \to e$.

Comment: Does it always stand that $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ||f||_n \rightarrow ||f||_{\infty}$$ ?? At which point do we use that $f$ is bounded and integrable?? @Math1000